# Official BIOS updates for Intel NUC NUC6i3SYH not working

Tags: bios, firmware, intel-nuc

I have a Intel NUC model 'NUC6i3SYH'. I verified the model name by running the 'Intel Software Update' utility.

My current BIOS version is - Ver 44 (SYSKLi35.86A.0044.2016.0512.1734). 
Latest BIOS version available on Intel website - Ver 61.

I downloaded the latest BIOS updates from here (EXE and BIO files) - https://downloadcenter.intel.com/search?keyword=NUC6i3SYH

EXE method - Once I run the installer, it asks to reboot to finish installing the BIOS, and  after reboot I get the following error message dialog - "CURRENT BIOS IS AN UNSUPPORTED LEGACY BIOS".

BIO file method - Loaded BIO file on a USB drive, detected by NUC through F7-mechanism, accepts BIO file and system reboots twice, then boots into Windows OS. No change in BIOS version.

Instead of jumping from ver 44 to ver 61, i tried going to ver 45 first. Same results.

Has anyone successfully updated BIOS on a Intel NUC (NUC6i3SYH)?

Answer (score 1):

For others it can apparently be caused by a bug in the reporting program that starts after reboot.
Source: https://communities.intel.com/thread/116477

To verify what version you have you can run this from command prompt:
`wmic bios get smbiosbiosversion`

I saw the same error but at least it reports I have the latest version. But I see for this poster it didn't update.

Comment: thank you for that command. i ran it, and it showed me that i was running an older version of the BIOS (ver 44). I then downloaded and ran the latest version (66) and it rebooted, and said 'update installed correctly'. But when i ran the wmic command, it still shows the older version.